# Get class name from element, and select all elements with the same class

Tags: jquery

```
$('.classToClick').live("click", function () {
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $(this).val("lol");
    $.post('post.php', {
        string: "lalala"
    }, function (data) {
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
    });
})
```

This code doesn't work, because in post we use `$(this)`. When we change it to `.classToClick`, it works.

How can we get the class of the element clicked so that we could use it like this?

```
$('.classToClick').live("click", function () {
    var className = $(this).name;
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $(this).val("lol");
    $.post('post.php', {
        string: "lalala"
    }, function (data) {
        $(className).removeAttr('disabled');
    });
})
```

Is it possible to do something similar?

Comment: it's not clear, do you want class name or element's name?

Comment: After almost 300 questions, certainly you can do a better job of formatting the code in your question. No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon clicking, you will need to capture the class name, which can be done via:

```
var className = $(this).attr('class'); //Alternatively, $(this).prop('class')
```

and when you later refer to it inside of the $ selector, you need to include the period to denote a class is being selected, as such:

```
$('.' + className).removeAttr('disabled');
```

**Code:**

```
$('.classToClick').live("click", function() 
{   
    var className = $(this).attr('class');    
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').val("lol");

    $.post('post.php', {string : "lalala"}, function(data)
    {
        $('.' + className).removeAttr('disabled');
    });
})
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hJsBR/)**

Comment: Omg, how couldn't I figure it out by myself. Thanks.

Comment: @hey - I added an example that will perform a mock post for you along with the functionality you needed.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
$('.classToClick').live("click", function() {       
   var $el = $(this);
   $el.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   $el.val("lol");
   $.post('post.php', {string : "lalala"}, function(data) {
       $el.removeAttr('disabled');
   });
});
```

Storing the jquery `el` in the var is a bit more efficient than calling `$(this)` again and again.  Have a google for Paul Irish and jQuery performance tips :)

Answer (score 0):

basically in the call back of the `$.post` `$(this)` represents nothing, you can assign $(this) to a variable and then use that variable for the processing something like this

```
var $field = $(this);
```

and then can use this as

```
$('.classToClick').live("click", function() {   
      var className = $(this).name;    
      $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $(this).val("lol");
      var field = $(this);
      $.post('post.php', {string : "lalala"}, function(data) {
        $(field).removeAttr('disabled');
      });
```

})

Answer (score 0):

You can also set a context for your callback.
As well the correct way to change a property on an element is with the `prop()` method.

```
$('body').on('click', '.classToClick', function() {    
   $(this).prop('disabled', true)
          .val("lol");
   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'post.php',
     context:  $(this)
     data: {
       string : "lalala"
     },
     success:  function(data) {
       this.prop('disabled', false);
     }
   });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).name` will mostly give you `undefined` or `null` value so it will not work. What you can do is store the reference to object in a local variable and then use it inside the post success handler. Try this.

```
$('.classToClick').live("click", function() {   
       var $elem = $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').val("lol");
       $.post('post.php', {string : "lalala"}, function(data) {
           $elem.removeAttr('disabled');
       });
});
```